# keeping rspec tests DRY

Tags: rspec

I have the following rspec test

```
 feature "#Create New User"  do

  scenario "Sign In" do
    sign_in
  end

  scenario "direct to create new user page" do
    click_link 'Admin'
    click_link 'User Maintenance'
    click_link 'Create'
  end

  it "user name must not be blank" do
    fill_in "user_name", :with => ""
    select2("Loanstreet", "UserType")
    expect(page).to have_content "Name can't be blank" 


  it "user name length must longer than 5" do
    fill_in "user_name", :with => "Euge"
    select2("Loanstreet", "UserType")
    expect(page).to have_content "Name length must be longer than 5" 

  end
end
```

My problem is that after the user signs in? the first scenario passes but then the rest fails. Is there a way of ensuring that the rest passes as well? I know it fails because of the "end" after the first scenario. so how do i do multiple tests in one page or nested tests in one page?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Note that `scenario`, [it](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup#it-class_method), and [specify](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup.specify) are aliases, so they do the same thing.

```
feature "#Create New User"  do

  # These two scenarios should not be like that, these are just 
  # preparations required by the other scenarios to pass
  # scenario "Sign In" do
  #  sign_in
  # end

  # scenario "direct to create new user page" do
  #  click_link 'Admin'
  #  click_link 'User Maintenance'
  #  click_link 'Create'
  # end

  # they should be used in a before hook, which will be run before 
  # each scenario
  before do
    sign_in        
    click_link 'Admin'
    click_link 'User Maintenance'
    click_link 'Create'
  end 

  # or you can make it a before :all so that it runs only once 
  # before all the scenarios
  # before :all do
  #  sign_in        
  #  click_link 'Admin'
  #  click_link 'User Maintenance'
  #  click_link 'Create'
  # end 

  # it "user name must not be blank" do
  scenario "changes user name with a blank string" do
    fill_in "user_name", :with => ""
    select2("Loanstreet", "UserType")
    expect(page).to have_content "Name can't be blank" 
  end

  # it "user name length must longer than 5" do
  scenario "changes user name with a string shorter than 5" do
    fill_in "user_name", :with => "Euge"
    select2("Loanstreet", "UserType")
    expect(page).to have_content "Name length must be longer than 5" 
  end
end
```

Comment: so each time i have to do the above actions in each scenario. Is there no other way of doing it only once and call the multiple tests. Or is the only way   rspec allows it? feel each time having to sign in seems like a lot of function repetition. But thanks for the answer @nafaa

Comment: You can do it in the `spec_helper` or `rails_helper` files, `Rspec.before do sign_in end` but this is not what this feature is for. If you want you can define a function that do the sign in. and just call it when you need it. This is the correct way to make examples setup and preparation, their is no other way, I guess.